# How to insert wysiwyg edited text into database

Tags: php, mysql

**The Idea**

I have a forum in my project and i'm trying to implement wysiwyg editor to post questions and answers. Actually the project is already completed and now i'm trying to implement NicEdit wysiwyg editor to all the required textareas. I'm using the following lines of prior to database insertion of posted data :

```
$post_body = $_POST['post_body'];
$post_body = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($post_body));
$post_body = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$post_body);
```

**Problem**

When I insert the posted data I'm getting the following output :

[image: OUTPUT]

**Conclusion**

I want to know how to insert the wysiwyg edited content into the database. Apart from this, please suggest me some nice wysiwyg plugins which are easy to embed in my project. Currently, i'm using NicEdit which is pretty easy to embed but with limited functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you decode it with: [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) before echoing?

That may solve your problem.

Edit:

You could do [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) and allow only few markup tags.

Eg:

`// Allow <p> and <a> echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');`

Thus you could strip risky tags like `<script>`

Comment: Why would you encode something as HTML before putting it into the database only to decode it to text afterwards? Better to remove the encoding step then muck about decoding it later.

Comment: But that will make my website prone to cross scripting attacks ryt?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
$post_body = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($post_body));
```

That is how you create an HTML representation of plain text. You are asking people to submit HTML, not plain text.

(Do, however, implement a whitelist based, HTML aware XSS filter such as HTML Purifier)

Comment: If i don't do that, I think my site will be vulnerable to scripting atacks. Am I correct?

Comment: I refer you back to the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: No, that's what `mysqli_real_escape_string` is for.

Comment: I seriously have no idea about the last line of your answer since i'm very new to programming.

Comment: There's a product recommendation in that line, google HTML Purifier. It has documentation.

Comment: Ok. I will see the documentation.

Comment: Apart from this, I want to implement a wysiwyg editor which can add code seperately just like this website. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Quentin that stops SQL injection but it can still be prone to XSS attacks

Comment: @Populus — See the last paragraph of my answer, and my first and third comments on it.

Comment: @Quentin oops sorry I looked only at your comment about `mysqli_real_escape_string`, and forgot this answer was yours as well :P